# How to add dll-override to wine config from command-line?

Tags: linux, command-line, wine

1. I know that I can add dll-overrides from wineconfig GUI:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX="$somedir" winecfg
   ```
2. I know that I can **temporarily** add dll-overrides from command-line by specifying `WINEDLLOVERRIDES` environment variable:

   ```
   WINEPREFIX="$somedir" WINEDLLOVERRIDES="$somedlloverrides" wine "$pathtoexe"
   ```

   But this will not change wine configs, just temporarily use changed settings.

I want to change wine config (specifically: add dll-override) from command-line.

Is there command-line tool that will help me to do it?

Comment: P.S.: May be I should ask it on http://stackoverflow.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exceprt code that does what you want, from a tool you want to look into: [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks):

```
w_override_dlls()
{
    w_skip_windows w_override_dlls && return

    _W_mode=$1
    case $_W_mode in
    *=*)
        w_die "w_override_dlls: unknown mode $_W_mode.
Usage: 'w_override_dlls mode[,mode] dll ...'." ;;
    disabled)
        _W_mode="" ;;
    esac
    shift
    echo Using $_W_mode override for following DLLs: $@
    cat > "$W_TMP"/override-dll.reg <<_EOF_
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DllOverrides]
_EOF_
    while test "$1" != ""
    do
        case "$1" in
        comctl32)
           rm -rf "$W_WINDIR_UNIX"/winsxs/manifests/x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2982_none_deadbeef.manifest
           ;;
        esac

        if [ "$_W_mode" = default ]
        then
            # To delete a registry key, give an unquoted dash as value
            echo "\"*$1\"=-" >> "$W_TMP"/override-dll.reg
        else
            # Note: if you want to override even DLLs loaded with an absolute
            # path, you need to add an asterisk:
            echo "\"*$1\"=\"$_W_mode\"" >> "$W_TMP"/override-dll.reg
            #echo "\"$1\"=\"$_W_mode\"" >> "$W_TMP"/override-dll.reg
        fi

        shift
    done

    w_try_regedit "$W_TMP_WIN"\\override-dll.reg

    unset _W_mode
}
```

This bash function first creates a `override-dll.reg` file in temp directory, then tries to import it into selected prefix using `regedit`. You can specify overrides like:

```
w_override_dlls native,builtin comctl32
```

Another useful function sets the override for specific application, like:

```
w_override_app_dlls winecfg.exe builtin comctl32
```

What you can do is write your own bash script using this as inspiration, or extend winetricks own functionality (google for writing winetricks verb metadata) for your use cases, or just use winetricks functions as a library.